# \thispagestyle{empty} on last page doesn´t work

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, chapters, koma-script

I need a site without page style at the end of a document. But the command doesn´t work. How can I solve this?

```
\documentclass[BCOR=10mm,DIV=11]
{scrreprt}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[
    automark,                               %% Kapitelangaben in Kopfzeile automatisch erstellen
    headsepline, 
    footsepline, 
    plainheadsepline, 
    plainfootsepline
]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\setkomafont{captionlabel}{\bfseries}           %% Label-Bildunterschrift fett
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\small}          %% Kopfzeile klein
%\setheadsepline{0.4pt}                         %% Kopf-Linie
%\setfootsepline{0.4pt}                         %% Fuß-Linie

\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\ihead[]{}
\chead[]{}
\ohead[\headmark]{\headmark}

\ifoot[]{}
\cfoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
\ofoot[]{}

\AfterTOCHead{\singlespacing}
\onehalfspacing
\KOMAoptions{DIV=last}

\begin{document}

\begin{spacing}{1}
\title{Titel}
\author{1}
\end{spacing}

\begin{spacing}{1}
\maketitle
\end{spacing}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Test}
\subsection{1}
\subsection{2}
\Blindtext

\chapter{Test1}
\subsection{1}
\subsection{2}
\Blindtext

\chapter{Test2}
\subsection{1}
\subsection{2}
\Blindtext

\chapter{Test3}
\subsection{1}
\subsection{2}
\Blindtext

\chapter{Test4}
\subsection{1}
\subsection{2}
\Blindtext

\chapter{Test4}
\subsection{1}
\subsection{2}
\Blindtext

\chapter{Test4}
\subsection{1}
\subsection{2}
\Blindtext

\chapter{Test4}
\subsection{1}
\subsection{2}
\Blindtext

\chapter{Test4}
\subsection{1}
\subsection{2}
\Blindtext

\chapter{Test4}
\subsection{1}
\subsection{2}
\Blindtext

\thispagestyle{empty}
\chapter*{Erklärung}
%\begin{flushleft}
\vspace*{10ex}
%\noindent\textit{Hiermit versichere ich, dass ich die vorliegende Abschlussarbeit selbstständig verfasst und keine anderen als die angegebenen Quellen und Hilfsmittel verwendet %habe.} \par\vspace{1ex}
%\noindent
\noindent\textit{Ich erkläre hiermit eidesstattlich, dass ich die vorliegende Arbeit selbständig angefertigt habe. Die aus fremden Quellen übernommenen Gedanken 
sind als solche kenntlich gemacht. Die Arbeit wurde bisher keiner anderen Prüfungsbehörde vorgelegt und auch nicht veröffentlicht. Ich bin mir bewusst, dass eine unwahre Erklärung rechtliche Folgen haben kann.}\par\vspace{3ex}
\noindent
\rule[0.0cm]{4.3cm}{0.4pt}\par
\noindent
\par\vspace{8ex}

\noindent\textit{Seitens des Verfassers bestehen keine Einwände, die Arbeit für die öffentliche Nutzung zur Verfügung zu stellen.} \par\vspace{3ex}
\noindent
\rule[0.0cm]{4.3cm}{0.4pt}\par
\noindent
%\end{flushleft}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Move it after the chapter: `\chapter*{Erklärung}\thispagestyle{empty}`

Comment: I´m sure I tried this before... Maybe it´s too late for me.

Comment: Did it work? If not, check you you have only one page there. If not, use `\pagestyle` instead of `\thispagestyle`.

Comment: It works. But now I hava another problem (only in my original document). Before this site there is a empty page from the list of figures. Means the lof generate a second page which is empty (only head).

Comment: I believe that your class is using `openright` option so any new chapter will start on a new right page.

Comment: Why don't you try with `\newpage \pagestyle{empty} \chapter*{Erklärung}`???

Comment: @Sigur But it´s only a single-sided document.

Comment: @Sigur In the preamble is not `openright=on/yes/true` I don't think so.

Comment: @Aradnix, you don't need to see it on preamble. It is included on the class file. Try `\documentclass[BCOR=10mm,DIV=11,openany]
{scrreprt}`.

Comment: @Sigur Is it possible to send you my files? They are good commented. But it´s hard do make a minimal example of this.

Comment: If you don't want blank pages when changing chapters use the option `openany` as I wrote.

Comment: @sigur By default the `scrreprt` class uses the options `\documentclass[abstract=false,captions=tablesignature,chapteratlists=10pt,chapterprefix=false,draft=false,fontsize=11pt,footsepline=false,headings=big,headsepline=false,listof=graduated,open=any,paper=a4,parindent=default,titlepage=true,toc=graduated,twocolumn=false,twoside=false,version=first]{scrreprt}` So you was right, and me too, because that option was not in the class file options of the MWE.

Comment: The problem for the blank page was a \clearpage after \lstlistoflistings

Comment: The issue can be resolved in its entirety by using the documented command `\addchap*{erklärung}` provided by KOMA-script. Hence marking it as a duplicate.